# Coding a multiple responses question using RSTUDIO

Tags: r, survey, multiple-results

Let's say we have this question *Why are you not happy?* and we have 5 answers (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

```
s = data.frame(subjects = 1:12,
  Why_are_you_not_happy = c(1,2,4,5,1,2,4,3,2,1,3,4))
```

in the previous example every subject picked only one option. but let's say that each of the subjects 3, 7 and 10 picked more than one option.

- subject 3 : options 1,2,5
- subject 7 : option 3,4
- subject 10 : option 1,5

I want to code the options of this question considering these multiple options for these 3 subjects, while preserving the shape of the dataframe.

The next case is if the dataframe includes 2 questions as follows :

```
df <- data.frame(subjects = 1:12,
                 Why_are_you_not_happy = 
                   c(1,2,"1,2,5",5,1,2,"3,4",3,2,"1,5",3,4),
                 why_are_you_sad = 
                   c("1,2,3",1,2,3,"4,5,3",2,1,4,3,1,1,1) )
```

How can we making the proper coding for the first and second scenario ?
The objective is to apply multiple correspondence analysis (MCA).

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit 1:

With your updated example data you have (at least) two options: you can separate each column, or you can `pivot_longer()` the data and group the "scores" together. E.g.

```r
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(subjects = 1:12,
                 Why_are_you_not_happy = 
                   c(1,2,"1,2,5",5,1,2,"3,4",3,2,"1,5",3,4),
                 why_are_you_sad = 
                   c("1,2,3",1,2,3,"4,5,3",2,1,4,3,1,1,1))
df
#>    subjects Why_are_you_not_happy why_are_you_sad
#> 1         1                     1           1,2,3
#> 2         2                     2               1
#> 3         3                 1,2,5               2
#> 4         4                     5               3
#> 5         5                     1           4,5,3
#> 6         6                     2               2
#> 7         7                   3,4               1
#> 8         8                     3               4
#> 9         9                     2               3
#> 10       10                   1,5               1
#> 11       11                     3               1
#> 12       12                     4               1

df1 <- df %>%
  separate(Why_are_you_not_happy,
           sep = ",", into = c("Why_are_you_not_happy_1",
                               "Why_are_you_not_happy_2",
                               "Why_are_you_not_happy_3")) %>%
  separate(why_are_you_sad,
           sep = ",", into = c("why_are_you_sad_1",
                               "why_are_you_sad_2",
                               "why_are_you_sad_3"))
#> Warning: Expected 3 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 11 rows [1, 2, 4,
#> 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12].
#> Warning: Expected 3 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 10 rows [2, 3, 4,
#> 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12].
df1
#>    subjects Why_are_you_not_happy_1 Why_are_you_not_happy_2
#> 1         1                       1                    <NA>
#> 2         2                       2                    <NA>
#> 3         3                       1                       2
#> 4         4                       5                    <NA>
#> 5         5                       1                    <NA>
#> 6         6                       2                    <NA>
#> 7         7                       3                       4
#> 8         8                       3                    <NA>
#> 9         9                       2                    <NA>
#> 10       10                       1                       5
#> 11       11                       3                    <NA>
#> 12       12                       4                    <NA>
#>    Why_are_you_not_happy_3 why_are_you_sad_1 why_are_you_sad_2
#> 1                     <NA>                 1                 2
#> 2                     <NA>                 1              <NA>
#> 3                        5                 2              <NA>
#> 4                     <NA>                 3              <NA>
#> 5                     <NA>                 4                 5
#> 6                     <NA>                 2              <NA>
#> 7                     <NA>                 1              <NA>
#> 8                     <NA>                 4              <NA>
#> 9                     <NA>                 3              <NA>
#> 10                    <NA>                 1              <NA>
#> 11                    <NA>                 1              <NA>
#> 12                    <NA>                 1              <NA>
#>    why_are_you_sad_3
#> 1                  3
#> 2               <NA>
#> 3               <NA>
#> 4               <NA>
#> 5                  3
#> 6               <NA>
#> 7               <NA>
#> 8               <NA>
#> 9               <NA>
#> 10              <NA>
#> 11              <NA>
#> 12              <NA>
```

This is what I think you should use for MCA, e.g.

```r
library(FactoMineR)
library(factoextra)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2

results <- MCA(df1[,2:7])
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

```r
# Check eigenvalues to see %var for each dimension
fviz_eig(results)
```

[image]

---

Second approach for handling the data that 'works better' for plotting with e.g. ggplot:

```r
df2 <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(-subjects,
               names_to = "Category",
               values_to = "Score") %>%
  separate(Score, sep = ",", 
           into = c("Score_1", "Score_2", "Score_3"))
#> Warning: Expected 3 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 21 rows [1, 3, 4,
#> 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, ...].
df2
#> # A tibble: 24 × 5
#>    subjects Category              Score_1 Score_2 Score_3
#>       <int> <chr>                 <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
#>  1        1 Why_are_you_not_happy 1       <NA>    <NA>   
#>  2        1 why_are_you_sad       1       2       3      
#>  3        2 Why_are_you_not_happy 2       <NA>    <NA>   
#>  4        2 why_are_you_sad       1       <NA>    <NA>   
#>  5        3 Why_are_you_not_happy 1       2       5      
#>  6        3 why_are_you_sad       2       <NA>    <NA>   
#>  7        4 Why_are_you_not_happy 5       <NA>    <NA>   
#>  8        4 why_are_you_sad       3       <NA>    <NA>   
#>  9        5 Why_are_you_not_happy 1       <NA>    <NA>   
#> 10        5 why_are_you_sad       4       5       3      
#> # … with 14 more rows

library(ggplot2)
# convert subjects from an integer to a factor
df2$subjects <- factor(df2$subjects)

group_labels <- c("Why_are_you_not_happy" = "Why are you not happy?",
                  "why_are_you_sad" = "Why are you sad?")

df2 %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(subjects, Category),
               names_to = "Score_number",
               values_to = "Answer") %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = subjects, y = Answer,
             fill = Category)) +
  geom_tile(color = "white") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = seq(0.5, 11.5, 1),
             color = "black") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = seq(0.5, 4.5, 1),
             color = "black") +
  scale_fill_discrete(labels = group_labels,
                      name = "") +
  theme_bw(base_size = 16) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        panel.grid = element_blank()) +
  coord_cartesian(expand = 0) +
  facet_wrap(~Category, nrow = 2,
             labeller = labeller(Category = group_labels))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

### Original answer:

It sounds like you want the `separate()` function from the [tidyr](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate.html) package, e.g.

```r
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(subjects = 1:12,
                 Why_are_you_not_happy = c(1,2,"1,2,5",5,1,2,"3,4",3,2,"1,5",3,4))
df
#>    subjects Why_are_you_not_happy
#> 1         1                     1
#> 2         2                     2
#> 3         3                 1,2,5
#> 4         4                     5
#> 5         5                     1
#> 6         6                     2
#> 7         7                   3,4
#> 8         8                     3
#> 9         9                     2
#> 10       10                   1,5
#> 11       11                     3
#> 12       12                     4

df %>%
  separate(Why_are_you_not_happy,
           sep = ",", into = c("Answer_1",
                               "Answer_2",
                               "Answer_3"))
#> Warning: Expected 3 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 11 rows [1, 2, 4,
#> 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12].
#>    subjects Answer_1 Answer_2 Answer_3
#> 1         1        1     <NA>     <NA>
#> 2         2        2     <NA>     <NA>
#> 3         3        1        2        5
#> 4         4        5     <NA>     <NA>
#> 5         5        1     <NA>     <NA>
#> 6         6        2     <NA>     <NA>
#> 7         7        3        4     <NA>
#> 8         8        3     <NA>     <NA>
#> 9         9        2     <NA>     <NA>
#> 10       10        1        5     <NA>
#> 11       11        3     <NA>     <NA>
#> 12       12        4     <NA>     <NA>
```

Or, perhaps in long format? E.g.

```r
df %>%
  separate(Why_are_you_not_happy,
           sep = ",", into = c("Answer_1",
                               "Answer_2",
                               "Answer_3")) %>%
  pivot_longer(-subjects) %>%
  na.omit()
#> Warning: Expected 3 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 11 rows [1, 2, 4,
#> 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12].
#> # A tibble: 16 × 3
#>    subjects name     value
#>       <int> <chr>    <chr>
#>  1        1 Answer_1 1    
#>  2        2 Answer_1 2    
#>  3        3 Answer_1 1    
#>  4        3 Answer_2 2    
#>  5        3 Answer_3 5    
#>  6        4 Answer_1 5    
#>  7        5 Answer_1 1    
#>  8        6 Answer_1 2    
#>  9        7 Answer_1 3    
#> 10        7 Answer_2 4    
#> 11        8 Answer_1 3    
#> 12        9 Answer_1 2    
#> 13       10 Answer_1 1    
#> 14       10 Answer_2 5    
#> 15       11 Answer_1 3    
#> 16       12 Answer_1 4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much for elaborating all the possible options to handle this issue.

Comment: I will also add another example to the question if you can help me handle the issue @jared_mamrot

Comment: I've updated my answer with another potential solution @Anas116; hopefully this helps you with your problem. If not, please post another question :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. but regarding the ggplot figure : the answers of the first question are different from the second one eventhough they have the same coding (1,2,3,4,5). How can we present the results in that case on the same figure you presented ? @jared_mamrot

Comment: Using `facet_wrap()`? I've edited my answer to illustrate @Anas116